# Bash auto-completion of variables adds additional white space at the end

Tags: bash, tab-completion

When I perform an auto-completion of a bash variable, an additional whitespace character is added at the end.

So this:

```
$FO[TAB]
```

Becomes this:

```
$FOO" "
```

I added the quotes in order to denote the white space. 
The problem is that some variables we use are directories and the white space is annoying since it has to be removed and a / has to be typed. Is it somehow possible to configure a behaviour like this

So this:

```
$FO[TAB]
```

Becomes this:

```
$FOO/
```

Or this:

```
cd $FO[TAB]
```

Becomes this:

```
cd $FOO/
```

Comment: You might want to see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339246/add-spaces-to-the-end-of-some-bash-autocomplete-options-but-not-to-others

Comment: There are several steps to consider: 1) Make `$FO[TAB]` complete to `$FOO`, 2) expand `$FOO` to its value, and 3) recognize that the value is a directory, and complete *it* with a trailing `/` and no space. 1) is the default, 2) can be accomplished with some `readline` settings and configuration. 3) is tricky, and will require at least some significant work with the programmable completion facilities.

Answer (score 3):

Better late answer than never!

The convenient completion directory names in variables was implemented in Bash 4.3. The Bash 4.3 checks whether a shell variable expands to a directory name and appends `/` to the word as appropriate.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue on CentOS 7 with bash 4.2. I could not find any solution/workaround on the internet. "yum upgrade bash" did also not help.

Finally I decided to compile/install the latest bash version (at time 4.4). I simply followed this blog: [How To Install Bash 4.4 On Linux Distributions](https://fossbytes.com/installing-gnu-bash-4-4-linux-distros/)

Tab-completion works as expected in 4.4. It seems this is a bug in 4.2.

Please note: After "make install" the executable is located in /usr/local/bin/ (/bin/bash remains untouched) so you want to adjust /etc/passwd to make the new version the default login shell for users.

HTH

Comment: The existing answer indicates upgrading from Bash 4.2 is the solution.  You make reference to a blog, but don't include any information from it, so we have no idea what you found important about it.