# Bash ls auto-completion of variables adds additional white space at the end

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, environment-variables

I use bash 4.4.19 in a gnome-terminal 3.28.2 on ubuntu 18.04.

I have had issues with tab-completions of directory variables in the console, which seemingly could be solved with

```
shopt -s direxpand 
shopt -s cdable_vars
```

Suppose I have a variable `FOO` defined in my .bashrc containing some path: `export FOO=/some/valid/path`

Uning it with `cd`, I get the following behaviour:

```
$ cd $FOO + [Tab] # nothing happens
$ cd $FOO/ + [Tab] # expands to /some/valid/path
```

which is fine so far.

when using it with `ls` however, I get a whitespace after the first expansion:

```
$ ls $FOO + [Tab] # I'm writing the results on the next line
$ ls $FOO[Space]
```

which is quite annoying.

Searching the web for a solution has been fruitless; Similar questions have been asked before on stackexchange pages, but no solution help:
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981764/bash-tab-completion-adds-extra-space-after-the-first-completion) suggests to modify the file  `/etc/bash_completion.d/acroread.sh`, but I don't have that file, or to

> edit /etc/bash_completion line 1587, change default to filenames (make a backup first).

but there is no `'default'` at that line in that file on my machine.
Same goes for the solutions posted in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41707/bash-auto-completion-with-added-spaces-why-and-how-to-fix).

[The answer for this question](https://superuser.com/questions/599651/bash-auto-completion-of-variables-adds-additional-white-space-at-the-end/879920) also says that the bug should be fixed for bash 4.3, but it isn't working for my bash 4.4

Comment: Note `shopt -s cdable_vars` is irrelevant to your examples that all use `$FOO`. This option makes `cd FOO` work (note the lack of `$`).

Comment: There is a very good reason why they expand differently: it makes sense for `cd` to take only a single argument, but `ls` is meant to be run with any number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Kubuntu I can do the following:

```
$ compopt cd
compopt +o bashdefault +o default +o dirnames +o filenames -o nospace +o plusdirs cd
$ compopt ls
compopt +o bashdefault +o default +o dirnames +o filenames +o nospace +o plusdirs ls
$
```

As you can see there is `-o nospace` (option enabled) for `cd` but `+o nospace` (option disabled) for `ls`. To make `ls` behave like `cd` when it comes to adding spaces after tab-completions I run this:

```
compopt -o nospace ls
```

Run it manually and check if it solves the problem. To permanently change the option, place the command at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, so each new interactive Bash session will run it automatically. No root access, no system-wide patch required.